# How to Create a Flutter Widget from a String

Tags: flutter, widget

I want to turn a String that is actually a widget inside into a full working widget

```
String container = "Container(color:Colors.red)";

Widget magicFunction(String s){
  //Some wizards work 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_widget
example https://github.com/dengyin2000/dynamic_widget/tree/master/example 
This package support the following Widget created from `String`

Container, Text, TextSpan, TextStyle, RaisedButton,Row, ...

code snippet

```
Future<Widget> _buildWidget(BuildContext context) async {
    return DynamicWidgetBuilder()
        .build(containerJson, context, new DefaultClickListener());
  }

Expanded(
          child: FutureBuilder<Widget>(
            future: _buildWidget(context),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Widget> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                print(snapshot.error);
              }
              return snapshot.hasData
                  ? SizedBox.expand(
                      child: snapshot.data,
                    )
                  : Text("Loading...");
            },
          ),
        ),
```

working demo of example code

[image]

working demo of full code

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dynamic_widget/dynamic_widget.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class DefaultClickListener implements ClickListener {
  @override
  void onClicked(String event) {
    print("Receive click event: " + event);
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  String containerJson = '''
{
  "type": "Container",
  "color": "#FF00FF",
  "alignment": "center",
  "child": {
    "type": "Text",
    "data": "Flutter dynamic widget",
    "maxLines": 3,
    "overflow": "ellipsis",
    "style": {
      "color": "#00FFFF",
      "fontSize": 20.0
    }
  }
}

''';

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  Future<Widget> _buildWidget(BuildContext context) async {
    return DynamicWidgetBuilder()
        .build(containerJson, context, new DefaultClickListener());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder<Widget>(
                future: _buildWidget(context),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Widget> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    print(snapshot.error);
                  }
                  return snapshot.hasData
                      ? SizedBox.expand(
                          child: snapshot.data,
                        )
                      : Text("Loading...");
                },
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```